# Python: something faster than not in for large lists?

Tags: python

I'm doing a project with word lists. I want to combine two word lists, but only store the unique words.

I'm reading the words from a file and it seems to take a long time to read the file and store it as a list. I intend to copy the same block of code and run it using the second (or any subsequent) word files. The slow part of the code looks like this:

```
    while inLine!= "":
        inLine = inLine.strip()
        if inLine not in inList:
            inList.append(inLine)
        inLine = inFile.readline()
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the slow(est) part of the program is the "not in" comparison. What are ways I can rewrite this to make it faster?

Comment: Convert `inList` to a `set(..)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists); answers include with and without preserving the original list order options

Answer (score 6):

Judging by this line:

```
if inLine not in inList:
    inList.append(inLine)
```

It looks like you are enforcing uniqueness in the `inList` container.  You should consider to use a more efficient data structure, such as an `inSet` set.  Then the `not in` check can be discarded as redundant, because duplicates will be prevented by the container anyway.

If insertion ordering must be preserved, then you can achieve a similar result by using an `OrderedDict` with null values.

Comment: Maybe you should add the main benefit of using sets in this case: Going from O(n) to O(1) average case complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine two lists and remove the duplicates, you could try something like this:

```
combined_list = list(set(first_list) | set(second_list))
```